# Motivation for definition of work

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, definition, displacement

Why do we take the dot product in the work energy theorem? Consider the integral
$$\int\vert\vec F\vert\vert d\vec r\vert$$
Why don't we define this to be work done for example, instead of $\int\vec F\cdot d\vec r$?
I conjecture that this integral gives one unuseful results, thus there is no point to consider it. For example, let $\vec F=( F,0,0)$ and $d\vec r=(0,d y,0)$. Thus above integral becomes
$$F\Delta y$$
Assume for simplicity that the object moves with uniform velocity in the $y$ direction. The above equation then becomes
$$Fv\Delta t$$ where $v$ is speed and $t$ is time.

Thus even a particle with no forces in the $y$ direction gives a non-zero result. This, to me, seems to be a problem from a practical point of view to make predictions.

Is my view correct and can it be generalized?

Comment: I'm not really sure what your question is here - when we come across useful and interesting concepts, we tend to give them names. You seem to be asking why we don't use the name *work* for a quantity which is not useful.

Comment: @J.Murray More precisely, I am asking what makes a quantity useful.

Comment: Your notation confuses me. You have an arrow over the x componentt of force instead of (Fx, 0, 0). Same for the distance differential, you have an arrow over the y component instead of (0,dy,0).

Comment: @BillOnne Apologies, I have corrected the notation now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is somewhat opinion-based, but in my view the definition of work as $W = \int \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf r$ is motivated by the work-energy theorem, which says that
$$\Delta \left(\frac{1}{2} mv^2\right) = \int \mathbf F \cdot\mathrm d\mathbf r$$
which follows directly from Newton's 2nd law by integrating both sides:
$$\mathbf F = m\mathbf a $$
$$\implies \int\mathbf F \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf r  = \int m \mathbf a \cdot \mathbf v \ \mathrm dt = \int \frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}m|\mathbf v|^2\right) \mathrm dt $$
$$\implies \int \mathbf F \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf r = \Delta \left(\frac{1}{2}m |\mathbf v|^2\right)$$

This is a very common way to manipulate 2nd order ODE's of the form $\ddot{\mathbf y} = \mathbf Q$; first one "dots" both sides with $\dot{\mathbf y}$ and then integrates with respect to time to obtain $\Delta\left(\frac{1}{2}|\dot{\mathbf y}|^2\right) = \int \mathbf Q \cdot \dot{\mathbf y} \ \mathrm dt = \int \mathbf Q \cdot \mathrm d \mathbf y$.

The impulse-momentum theorem similarly follows from Newton's 2nd law via integrating with respect to $t$ instead of $\mathbf r$:
$$\mathbf F = m \mathbf a$$
$$\implies \int \mathbf F \ \mathrm dt = \int m \mathbf a \ \mathrm dt = \int \frac{d}{dt}(m\mathbf v) \mathrm dt$$
$$\implies \int \mathbf F \ \mathrm dt = \Delta(m\mathbf v)$$

There are other reason why work, kinetic energy, impulse, and momentum are useful quantities, but their definitions most naturally arise (again, in my opinion) from the formal manipulation of Newton's 2nd law.

Comment: Can you expand on how work energy follows directly from the 2nd law? It surely does in the 1D case, but in the 3D case, I am not so sure. One can motivate in the 3D case by adding three 1D cases, 1 for each dimension (This is essentially what Morin did in his book, for example), but then the question becomes why are we ignoring cross terms like $Fy$, which I mentioned in the post.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist Done

Comment: The use of dot product doesn't seem natural to me, or equivalently, this is same as adding three 1D equations.  As you said, it might be a matter of opinion after all.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist The critical step comes in identifying the fact that $\mathbf a \cdot \mathbf v  = \frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}|\mathbf v|^2$, which is just the chain rule (as applied to vector calculus). In that sense, it is very natural. If you are not familiar with vector calculus or the chain rule, it may seem less natural of course.

Comment: Writing $\vec a\cdot\vec v$ as $\frac{d}{dt}v^2$ is indeed natural, I agree with that. What isn't natural, is to take the dot product of force with displacement vector. The same is the case when studying electromagnetism. There too for example, we consider fluxes and curls right at the start without any motivation. However one can at least make a little sense of them by considering flux and curl to be a natural mathematical step in a theory concerned with vector fields. But in defining work there is no motivation like that.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist If you have a 2nd-order ODE of the form $\ddot{\mathbf y}(t) = \mathbf Q$, an *extremely* common technique is to "dot" both sides with $\dot{\mathbf y}$ and then integrate with respect to $t$, which yields $\Delta\big(\frac{1}{2}|\dot{\mathbf y}|^2 \big)= \int \mathbf Q \cdot\dot{ \mathbf y}\ \mathrm dt = \int \mathbf Q \cdot \mathrm d\mathbf y$ This is *precisely* what we're doing here. Like I said, natural-ness is in some sense in the eye of the beholder, but this is among the most elementary possible manipulations of a vector equation.

Comment: I see. I didn't knew about it being that common. Please add this to your answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: @GedankenExperimentalist Done

Answer (score 3):

In this answer I expand on the answer by contributor J.Murray by giving a different way to derive the work-energy theorem from $F=ma$

(This treatment shows that the mathematical tools of vector calculus are not a *necessity* for deriving the work-energy theorem. The sufficient means are: differentiation and integration.)

First the case of motion with a single spatial degree of freedom. After that I will give the generalization to multiple spatial degrees of freedom.

t time
s position
v velocity
a acceleration

The derivation hinges on the following two relations between 's', 'v' and 'a':

$$ v = \frac{ds}{dt}  \quad  \Leftrightarrow  \quad ds = v \ dt   \tag{1}  $$

$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt}  \quad  \Leftrightarrow  \quad dv = a \ dt  \tag{2}  $$

To derive the work-energy theorem the starting point is Newton's second law:

$$ F = ma \tag{3} $$

The next step is to integrate both sides with respect to the spatial coordinate, integrating from starting point $s_0$ to final point $s$

$$ \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds = \int_{s_0}^s ma \ ds \tag{4} $$

We proceed to work out the right hand side. I omit the factor $m$ temporarily, it is a multiplicative factor that is just carried over each step

$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds \tag{5}  $$

The following is valid for arbitrary acceleration profile. A this point we have no specification of how the accceleration changes over time, but we can still proceed because $a$ and $s$ are not independent; they are related by way of (1) and (2)

Use (1) to change the differential from $ds$ to $dt$. Since the differential is changed the limits change accordingly.

$$ \int_{t_0}^t a \ v \ dt \tag{6} $$

Change the order:

$$ \int_{t_0}^t v \ a \ dt  \tag{7} $$

Change of differential according to (2), with corresponding change of limits.

$$ \int_{v_0}^v v \ dv  \tag{8} $$

So we have:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s a \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}v^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}v_0^2  \tag{9} $$

We multiply both sides with $m$, and then the right hand side of (9) gives us the right hand side of (4). The result: the Work-Energy theorem:

$$ \int_{s_0}^s F \ ds = \tfrac{1}{2}mv^2 - \tfrac{1}{2}mv_0^2  \tag{10} $$

**Generalization to multiple degrees of freedom**

We have Pythagoras' theorem:

$$ a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \tag{11} $$

Which generalizes to three spatial degrees of freedom (and higher if you would want to.)

$$ {s_1}^2 + {s_2}^2 + {s_3}^2 = {|\vec s|}^2 \tag{12} $$

The counterpart of that for the velocity vector decomposed in vector components:

$$ {v_1}^2 + {v_2}^2 + {v_3}^2 = {|\vec v|}^2 \tag{12} $$

We have:
The fact that the expression $\tfrac{1}{2}mv^2$ is quadratic in $v$ dovetails with Pythagoras' theorem.

We can evaluate the work done for the spatial degrees of freedom individually, which gives kinetic energy components for each of the spatial degrees. The sum of the component kinetic energies is equal to the value $\tfrac{1}{2}m{|\vec v|}^2$